# Proxy server software that can embed/bundle javascript

Tags: web-server, apache, proxy, nginx

I'm required to speed up access to a specific website, which is terribly slow. I have no access to the source code/configuration of that server. After analysis, I figure out the problem:

- The server is far from customer's location, so latency is high - about 400ms
- The html pages have many `<script src="...">` tags, each of which require a separate request to load.
- The browser only send 6-8 requests at a time, thus it would take at least 5s to fetch all the js files for one page

*Caching of the js files is not viable* because js file name and content are dynamically generated by the server.

So I'm trying to set up a (reverse?) proxy server with low latency connection to the original server. When customer request a .html file, the proxy server should get the file from original server, parse it, find all `<script src="...">`, fetch the javascript, and embed the javascript code into `<script>` tag (and removing src="...") then return the bundled html. This way the browser doesn't need to send additional requests to get js files, and the latency doesn't accumulate

**The question(s)**:

- Is there a proxy server software with that feature available? Or maybe a nginx module/script?
- If customer's browser support HTTP/2, will a HTTP/2 proxy server solve the issue?
- Do you have any other solution to this problem?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google has developed an nginx and apache module with a lot of useful optimizations. One of them is javascript minification and concatenation. I have never tryed it but it seems to be what you are looking for https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-combine

Another solution would be using something like webpack to bundle all your javascript files. But it would require a few changes on your code base.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Following your link, I found another module that seems to fit my need: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-inline. I'm trying it, will report if it works.